# Azure slow communication between APIs

Tags: azure, rest, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-insights

In some 1-5% of our requests, we are seeing slow communication between APIs (REST API requests). Both APIs are developed by us and hosted on Azure, each app service on its own app service plan in the same region, P1v2 tier.

What we are seeing on application insights is that POST or GET requests on origin API can take a few seconds to execute, while real execution time on destination API is only a few milliseconds.

Examples (first line POST request on origin, second execution time on destination API): [slow req 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4lC7R.png), [slow req 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJMzs.png)

Our best guess is that the time difference is lost in communication between components. We don't have an explanation for it since the payload is really small and in most cases, communication takes less than 5 milliseconds.

We dismiss the possible explanation it could be due to component cold start since it happens during constant load and no horizontal scaling was performed.

Do you have any idea what might cause it or how to do additional analysis in order to discover it?

Comment: “*how to do additional analysis in order to discover it?*” At this point, I’d be reaching out to Azure Support for them to diagnose on their end.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running multiple sites on the App Service Plan, then enable the "**`Always On`**" setting for your **web app > All Settings > Application Settings >** Click on `Always On`

See here for details:  https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-configure/

When **`Always On`** is off, the site is shut down after 20 minutes of inactivity to free up resources for any additional websites that might be using the same App Service Plan.

---

The amount of information it needs to collect, process and then present itself requires some time, and involve internal calls as well, that is why considering the server load and usage, it takes around 6 to 7 seconds sometimes even more.
To [Troubleshoot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/troubleshoot-response-timeout-and-errors) that latency, try [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/general/performance-hit-api-calls) steps, provided by Microsoft.